# Programming practices when receiving and manipulating received TCP/HTTP data?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, tcp, dotnet-httpclient

Should data manipulation once data is returned either with TCP or HTTP be received as byte arrays or is it an O.K. practice to receive it as a string? I've been trying to find some professional projects on github to get my answer, but have had no luck. Some examples of HTTPClient from Microsoft on MSDN usually make use of the GetByteArrayAsync(website) method, instead of GetStringAsync(website). Is there any reason why they would use GetByteArrayAsync instead of GetStringAsync, which would make data manipulation much easier right off the bat? Are there any advantages to using GetByteArrayAsync first instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What moves "through the wire" are bytes, not strings.
They might be text, but can be pictures, or a zip file.
At TCP/HTTP level this is unknown, and it does not matter.
That decision belongs with a higher level.

HTTP has a bit more info than TCP, so you might have a mimetype to help you decide what those bytes are.

Even if you know it is some kind of text, you will need to know the character set. You might get that info in the HTTP header, or in the document itself, or there might be a standard saying what the encoding is.

Only then you will be able to convert to a string.

Comment: This answered my question perfectly. Thank you for clarifying this.